# Step-by-step resolution of the homogeneous $2^{nd}$ order differential equation of the wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics

I am trying to solve this homogeneous $2^{nd}$ order differential equation of the wave :

$$\frac{\partial^2{\sigma}}{\partial x^2}-\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2{\sigma}}{\partial t^2}=0$$

I am trying to solve it but I cannot derive this plane wave expression:

$$\sigma=\sigma_{0}e^{-i\omega t}e^{-ikx}$$

where $k$ is the wavenumber and $\omega=2\pi f$, where $f$ is the frequency.

Can you give me a step to step resolution of this differential equation? I found a lot of books but  they always arrive to different expressions of the wave.

I  can start separating the variable $\sigma(x,t)$ in $f(x)g(t)$ obtaining

$$\frac{\partial^2{f(x)g(t)}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2{f(x)g(t)}}{\partial t^2}$$
Subsequently I obtain
$$
 \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\partial^2{f(x)}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2} 
 \frac{1}{g(t)}\frac{\partial^2{g(t)}}{\partial t^2} = C
$$

Comment: What do you get when you differentiate your $\sigma(x,t)$ wrt $x$ twice? What do you get when you do the same wrt $t$? What do you get when you plug these two expressions into the wave equation? Remember that the resulting equation has to be true for all $x$ and all $t$, in particular it has to be true when $\sigma(x, t)$ is non-zero.

Comment: Hi Mardy Owens. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Starting with separation of variables: $\sigma(x,t) = f(x) g(t)$. Plug this trial function into the wave equation. Then try to split two variable into different parts. You will get two separate equations for $F(x)$ and $g(t)$, and a relation between the separation constants. Solve each equation.Then put two solutions together rendering the function you post.

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry I thought it was about school. I left school ten years ago :), I am just studying by myself and in the book I am ready they jump from the differential equation to its solution.

Comment: Dear @ytlu, I updated the questions, my problem start right after the separation of variables (I knew it because this method is also used for the Fourier Eq.). I am actually rusty in the resolution of 2nd order differential equation. I cannot recall the theory to arrive to a exponential resolution, that's why I asked for a step by step resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your separation is not yet complete:

$$
\frac{\partial^2{f(x)g(t)}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2{f(x)g(t)}}{\partial t^2}
$$
where each side of the equation contains both $x$ and $t$.

One more step to split them:
$$
 \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\partial^2{f(x)}}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2} 
 \frac{1}{g(t)}\frac{\partial^2{g(t)}}{\partial t^2} = C = -k^2
$$
The left hand side has only $x$, and left hand side has only $t$. Therefore, you may equate both side to a constant C. The constant $C$ has to be negative. let's say $C= -k^2$.
(You may think what will go wrong if $C \ge 0$.)

Write these two ordinary differntial equations:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2{f(x)}}{d x^2} &= -k^2 f(x);\tag{1}\\ \
\frac{d^2{g(t)}}{d t^2} &= -\omega^2 g(t). \tag{2};\\
 \text{ and }  k^2 &= \frac{\omega^2}{v^2}
\end{align}
The partial differentials are replaced by total differential.

This is constant coefficient second order differential equation. Beginning of any DE book will give you the solution
\begin{align}
f(x) &= A e^{\pm ikx};\\
g(t) &= B e^{\pm i\omega t};\\
\end{align}

Put these two together to obtain $\sigma (x,t)= f(x) g(t)$ with a arbitrary constant.

Comment: then I have a system of two differential Eq.s, what I don't understand is how to arrive to the final solution. I don't know how to solve each differential equation

Comment: The solution is $\sigma = f(x) g(t)$ and you put it together once you solve each of the separate equations $$\begin{gather} f'' = C f \\ g'' = v^2 C g \end{gather}$$

Comment: Yes but why the solution of the first is $Ae^{-ikx}$ and of the second $Be^{-i\omega t}$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any advice for a very basic DE book?

Comment: Any one will work for this purpose.  Therefore,  the simpler the better.

Comment: Wouldn’t complex exponentials need a minus side in front of the second derivative? $i^2=-1$

Comment: Yes. My mistake. We have to set the constant $C$ to be negative $-k^2$. Otherwise, the solutions become exponential grows indefinitely at eithe $\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Edited.

Comment: A question: I've seen $v$ called as propagation velocity of the wave, in my opinion is more correct to call it as phase velocity. What do you think?

Comment: @MardyOwens Yes. It is indeed a phase velocity.